# Hyperlink in Visual Basic Windows Form is only partially clickable in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to place a hyperlink in my Visual Basic Windows Form program in Visual Studio 2017.  Only a few of the letters in my hyperlink are clickable (blue underlined).  How do I get the entire hyperlink to be clickable (blue and underlined link)?

Here is my code:

```
lnkRules.Text = "Craps rules"
lnkRules.Links.Add(6, 4, "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Craps")
```

I don't know what the 6 and 4 do.

Comment: I honestly don't understand how you can possibly be asking this question. What are those 6 and 4 values for? Why have you included them in the first place?

Comment: I've been banned for one month for having mistakenly moderated a legit comment. Now who allowed this to be posted need to be banned too.

Comment: "I don't know what the 6 and 4 do." - Instead of blindly copying example code, read the rest of the [documentation for the method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.linklabel.linkcollection.add?view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_Forms_LinkLabel_LinkCollection_Add_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Object_); the descriptions for the `start` and `length` parameters are self explanatory. Also, if you type the code instead of pasting and editing selected parts, you get the benefit of Intellisense prompts for the parameters without having to go to the documentation page,

Answer (score 0):

If you want the entire text of your LinkLabel to be a link, then use code like this:

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    lnkRules.Text = "Craps rules"
    lnkRules.Links.Add(0, lnkRules.Text.Length, "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Craps")
End Sub

Private Sub lnkRules_LinkClicked(sender As Object, e As LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs) Handles lnkRules.LinkClicked
    Process.Start(e.Link.LinkData.ToString)
End Sub
```